# What’s the function of the て form in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form, manga

For context, I’m reading Haikyuu!! and I'm stuck on this sentence:

> コート中央のネットを挟んで2チームでボールを打ち合う。

The verb 挟む is in the て form, but I can’t understand why, so I don’t get the sentence. Is it connecting actions with an “and” or is there a use of the て form here I'm not getting?

Comment: How do you understand the verb 挟む in this sentence?

Comment: As @aguijonazo notes, it would help us to formulate a better answer if you could supply us with your best guess at translating / explicating the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: It's simply connecting two actions like an "and", so I don't understand why you don't understand the sentence. You've probably got something wrong at the other part of the sentence. Please try to explain everything you've got so far about this sentence.

Comment: I guess I don’t really understand the meaning of 挟む, because I don’t get what the subject of the sentence is. Is it “the net on the center of the court is inserted/is between two things/is across”? Or something like the net crosses the center of the court? The grammar is tripping me up

Comment: And the second part, two teams exchange blows with the ball? Unless the subject for the whole sentence is “two teams” so it could be something like “Two teams are on either side of the net at the center of the court AND they hit the ball”

Comment: You can understand the subject to be unspecified "people."

Answer (score 2):

The te-form by itself is just "and" or "by". Xを挟む basically means "to put X between two things" or "to sandwich X", and here "two things" refers to the two teams of a volleyball game. The 5th definition of 挟む in jisho is specifically about this usage:

> #### [挟む](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8C%9F%E3%82%80)
>
> 5. to be on either side of (a road, table, etc.); to have between each other; to be across (a street, river, etc.)​
>
> > 彼らはテーブルをはさんで向かい合った。They confronted each other across the table.

Therefore:

> コート中央のネットを挟んで...
>
> (facing each other) across the net in the center of a court (and) ...

This 2チームで is an adverbial expression meaning something like "on a two-team basis". See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/77721/5010), too. English has a word that corresponds to 1人で ("alone"), but somehow lacks expressions that correspond to 2人で, 5人で, 2チームで and so on. So a very literal translation would be "(People) sandwich the net in the center of a court, and (then) mutually hit a ball on a two-team basis".

Comment: Oh, I see! I read on Tofugu that で could be used to specify groups of people so I had a feeling that’s what it was. Thank you so much for your reply!